# Twitter Bootstrap: multiple modal on same page, want different background colors

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 modals on a page, see: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals. I want them to have different page background colors. The JS seems to generate `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to set a class or something to it via Bootstrap config?

Comment: the twitter bootstrap doc doesn't have anything on that, why not add with css or js?

Comment: adding a class to the mark up does nothing to the <div> that the JS creates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't, by any configuration, set the `backdrop` color, the only way is to change it by an event.

Let's assume this example: http://jsbin.com/uwelok/1/

You will need to set a new class on the `shown` event, like:

```
$('#m2').on('shown', function () {
    $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('backdrop-yellow');
});
```

there is no need to reset it, as upon the modal `hide` itself, the element is removed and created again, using the default configuration upon the next `show`.

and with such trick, you can have a simple class as:

```
.backdrop-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: One of the colors is "transparent". Is there a way not to show the backdrop?

Comment: the behaviour of a modal, is to bring that "window" upfront and remove the focus of the user from anything rather than that window. Maybe what you want is simple to show an alert? - BTW, this method still works if you give `transparent` as the background color: http://jsbin.com/uwelok/2/

Comment: Other trick is to make you `backdrop-yellow` rule as `opacity: 0;` that will remove any color as well.

Comment: Note that the opacity is set to 0.8 on the backdrop as well - so the color defined in .backdrop-yellow will have 'opacity: 0.8' applied to it unless you override it (unless of course it's transparent :-).